# Passing data from controllerA to controllerB using delegate

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I am trying to send simple data from viewControllerA to viewControllerB using delegate  but can not find The problem in my code.here is the code

in `ViewControllerA.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewControllerA;

@protocol viewControllerADelegate <NSObject>
-(void) addItem: (ViewControllerA *)controller data:(NSString *)item;
@end

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@property (assign) id<viewControllerADelegate> delegate;
@end
```

in`ViewControllerA.m`

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerA ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

 }

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:        (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
[self.delegate addItem:self data:@"this is data"];

  }
 @end
```

and here is `ViewControllerB.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController<viewControllerADelegate>

 @end
```

and `ViewControllerB.m`

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
 #import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
ViewControllerA *vba = [[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
[vba setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); 
 }
-(void) addItem: (ViewControllerA *)controller data:(NSString *)item{
NSLog(@"delegate function called");
}

@end
```

The implemented function `-(void) addItem: (ViewControllerA *)controller data:(NSString *)item` is never called.Am I missing something ? Thanks in advance

Comment: try changing the property type in VCA.h to (nonatomic)?

Comment: also, be sure that IB is completely linked up.

Comment: I used storyboard and everything was linked up. tried changing the property type nonatomic but no result.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using storyboards? If yes, you just push the wrong button: storyboard initializes view controllers on its own, so yours code:

```
ViewControllerA *vba = [[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
[vba setDelegate:self];
```

just setting delegate on some unused view controller.
Use segues, don't try to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: Actually I want to learn How to do it using delegates without using segues.thats why I posted it. and what is the solution of doing it using delegates ?

Comment: You need a reference to an existing view. Maybe you can take advantage of using `superview` here, but I'm not shure this is good solution. 
Usually you don't need a reference to an instance initialized by storyboard. That's just bad example of using delegate pattern.